# Using Java reflection returns all nulls

Tags: java, spring, reflection, null, powermock

I'm quite lost on this one. I have some acceptence tests running with JUnit4 based on Spring. Now I also want to add Unit Tests. To make them fast I skip the context and Inject the Mocks with PowerMock. 
However all of the sudden reflection wont work any more.

```
public class TestSomething {
    @Test
    public void nothingWrongWithThis() {
        Class<?> type = Client.class;
        type.getDeclaredMethods();
    }
}
```

The second line will return null like any other method call to the type except getName()

If I use a context however it will work:

```
@TransactionConfiguration
@ContextConfiguration({ "classpath:dw-product-context-test.xml" })
@Transactional
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
public class TestSomething {
    @Test
    public void nothingWrongWithThis() {
        Class<?> type = Client.class;
        type.getDeclaredMethods();
    }
}
```

What's wrong here? Shouldn't reflection work without any runner or context?

Not even adding the line

```
private Client client = new Client();
```

will change anything (Thought maybe the runtime needed to initialize the class in order to be able to reflect upon it)

Oh and adding the

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
```

won't change anything either.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

PS: Will be out of town for a day starting now, so I'll read any answer in around 35 hours.

---

**Edit**

Just figured out what was going on: 
I started in my debugger and opened `Client.class.declaredMethods` which was `null`. When I run `getDeclaredMethods()` it will get them however. So it looked as if everything was null at first which confused me but the debugger just didn't run `get...()` on all fields leaving them `null` initially

If I use a spring context it will load all beans (`Client` is an `@Entity`) and fill all the reflection fields with soft references just as if I called `get..()` on all of them.

Comment: Do you use any load time weaving? Are you sure that both tests use the same `Client` class (same package)?

Comment: How can `type.getDeclaredMethods();` return `null`, or do you mean, it is returning an empty array?

Comment: Thanks for your comments. Figured it out, check my edit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just figured it out: Missing knowledge about how reflections work when used in a debugger ;) Check my edit... Will mark this as answered but leave it as reference.